# urllib2 post timeout in python

Tags: python, timeout, urllib2

I'm possting a file to a webserver using urllib2.py in my script and it keeps timining out. My code:

```
def postdata(nodemac,filename,timestamp):
    try:
        wakeup()
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(TIMEOUT)
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(MultipartPostHandler.MultipartPostHandler)
        host = HOST
        func = "post_data"
        url = "http://{0}{1}?f={2}&nodemac={3}&time={4}".format(host, URI, func, nodemac, timestamp)
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            data = {"data":open(filename,"rb")}
            response = opener.open(url, data, timeout=TIMEOUT)
            retval = response.read()
            if "SUCCESS" in retval:
                return 0
            else:
                print "RETVAL "+retval
                return 99
        else:
            print filename +" is not a file"
            return 99
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        return 99
```

I set TIMEOUT to 20, 60 and 120 but the same thing keeps happening. What's going on with that I'm wondering? Something is foul! The timeout set to 20 used to work just fine and then all of a sudden, today it started to time out on me... does anyone have any clues? I couldn't find anything that brought me further on the web so I thought I'd try here...!

Thanks,

**Traceback:**

```
 File "gateway.py", line 686, in CloudRun
    read_img()
  File "gateway.py", line 668, in read_img
    retval = database.postimg(mac,fh,timestmp)
  File "/root/database.py", line 100, in postimg
    response = opener.open(url, data, timeout=TIMEOUT)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 394, in open
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 412, in _open
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 372, in _call_chain
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1199, in http_open
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1174, in do_open
URLError: <urlopen error timed out>
```

Comment: What is the actual traceback?

Comment: Maybe the server is not responding, so the timeout is perfectly valid? (What happens if you try to just visit the same URL in a web browser? What if you visit the same URL with `&data="foo"` added to the end of it?) Or maybe something is wrong with your network? If the exact same code that used to work no longer does, something in the environment has changed, and you've told us absolutely nothing about that environment, so all we can do is offer vague hints on tracking down the problem…

Answer (score 0):

> The timeout set to 20 used to work just fine and then all of a sudden, today it started to time out on me... does anyone have any clues?

Well, the first clue is that the behavior changed even though your code didn't. So, it's got to be something with the environment.

The most likely possibility is that the timeouts are a perfectly accurate sign that the server is overloaded, broken, etc. But, since you gave us no information at all about the server you're trying to talk to, it's hard to do much more than guess.

Here are some ideas for tracking down the problem.

First, take that exact same URL, paste it into your browser's address bar, and see what happens. Does it time out? Or take longer than 20 seconds to respond?

Try adding `&data=data` to the end of the URL.

Try using a simple tool to send the request as a POST. For example, from the command line, try `curl -d data http://whatever`.

Try logging exactly what headers and post data `urllib2` used, and making `curl` send exactly the same thing. (If this fails, and the previous one worked, you may want to edit your question, or ask a new question, with "Why did this work and that fail?" with the details.)

Try running the same tests from a different computer with a different internet connection.